# Special characters in window.open

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am trying to open a url in another tab using window.open. 
The problem is the ' character

```
"javascript:if(w=window.open('https://wiki.abc.com/display/New%27s+Project'));";
```

It renders into ' correctly but the first ' and the url's ' character form a group and ignore the last character and then i get a url not found error

Comment: escape the %27 with a \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace %27 with & apos; and the problem is solved.

`"javascript:if(w=window.open('https://wiki.abc.com/display/New&apos;s+Project'));";`